# Learning Differential Geometry

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, recreational-mathematics

What levels of mathematics does one need to nail down before successfully studying Differential Geometry?

Comment: I'm guessing multivariate calculus with differential forms.

Comment: How do you earn reputation on here haha

Comment: One can always try to study differential geometry and figure out what holes their knowledge has, and then fill them. I would imagine that if you are comfortable with proofs and calculus, you'd probably survive this method.

Comment: Yes! That is a handy method of learning mathematics. I have a solid, solid calculus, linear algebra, and DE foundation, so I'm thinking about diving right in and using our aforementioned method. Any suggestions on books? Dover? Schaums? Textbooks?

Comment: Ever since last week's 100 year relativity anniversary, I got to re-hear Einstein's story and after he developed special relativity, he was forced to learn differential geometry and make the necessary changes to his theory. And now it's got me wanting to learn differential geometry! So I will!

Comment: Millman/Parker's [**Elements of Differential Geometry**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0132641437) is a good place to begin if you're not ready for the more advanced books that tend to get mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the direct link to amazon, Dave!

Comment: Check out my *free* text linked in my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Good knowledge of Calculus. Basic topology to multiple integrals, Gauss-Ostrogradsky formula.
2. Good knowledge of euclidean 2d/3d geometry.
3. Functional analysis, topology, linear algebra.

For some books you can use, check [here on physics forums.](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/best-books-for-differential-geometry.55317/)

Comment: You don't need functional analysis to *start* learing differential geometry.  For that matter, you don't really need topology at the undergrad level (meaning DG of curves of surfaces) either.

Comment: I aggree that one does not need functional analysis. I disagree that one does not need at least the primitive concepts of topology: a lot of things can be mysterious and devoid of intuition without topology.

Furthermore, there is no need for 2d/3d geometry. Also one needs good knowledge of analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (explicitly, Inverse Function Theorem).